# can't open external Tool from c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to open an external exe file with parameters, but it seems, that my path is beeing destroyed by escaping.

Here the code, perhaps you can point my nose to the error.

```
void open_2x()
{
   string var_2x_apppath = "\"%PROGRAMFILES%\\2X\\Client\\TSClient.exe\"";
   string var_2x_parameter = " s!='"+var_ausgabe_serverip+"' a!='"+var_ausgabe_produkt+"' t!='"+var_ausgabe_ServerPort+"' d!='"+var_ausgabe_raum+"' u!='"+var_ausgabe_User+"' q!='"+var_ausgabe_PW+"' m!='"+var_ausgabe_mode+"'";

   MessageBox.Show(var_2x_apppath + var_2x_parameter); //for debug only

   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
   p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
   p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + var_2x_apppath + var_2x_parameter;
   p.Start();
   p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Temporarily change your call to `/k` instead of `/c`, so that it doesn't terminate after execution. Then, copy the contents of batch output - it should tell you what is the actual problem. Btw, where is the drive letter in your path?

Comment: hi, %PROGRAMFILES% =  [DriveLetter]:\Program Files\ in Windows Environment. Shouldn't  it Work?

Comment: Ah, I see. It should work. Try changing to `/k` and copy the error message. Now, we can't know what exactly isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the environment variable %PROGRAMFILES% via *[GetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6(v=vs.110).aspx)*

```
void open_2x()
{
    var programfiles = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROGRAMFILES");
    string var_2x_apppath = System.IO.Path.Combine(programfiles, "2X", "Client", "TSClient.exe");     
    string var_2x_parameter = " s!='"+var_ausgabe_serverip+"' a!='"+var_ausgabe_produkt+"' t!='"+var_ausgabe_ServerPort+"' d!='"+var_ausgabe_raum+"' u!='"+var_ausgabe_User+"' q!='"+var_ausgabe_PW+"' m!='"+var_ausgabe_mode+"'";

    MessageBox.Show(var_2x_apppath + var_2x_parameter); //for debug only

    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + var_2x_apppath + var_2x_parameter;
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort.

Funny thing is, that Variable programfiles points to "C:\Program Files (x86)" but i need the 64bit folder.

Comment: If you're using .NET4 you could also try to use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles), see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When parameters or command has spaces you should use double quote. Take a look at this [site](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html). Maybe your parameters are with spaces.

Answer (score -1):

You should use something like this:

```
string.Format("C:\\{0}\\{1}", Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles, @"2X\Client\TSClient.exe\")
```

RESULT: "C:\ProgramFiles\2X\Client\TSClient.exe\"

Comment: Hi, thanks, but the \\ is working too. 

If i change %PROGRAMFILES% to C:\Program Files, it is working, but i would like to use the windows environment variable.

Comment: So then you should use something like this:
string.Format("C:\\{0}\\{1}", Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles, @"2X\Client\TSClient.exe\")
RESULT: "C:\\ProgramFiles\\2X\\Client\\TSClient.exe\\"

Comment: I think you could reuse your code combined with my solution. My solution was just to explain you how it works